# How to group-by without writing select in select

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Im trying to write an sql script in oracle which group-by data from different columns.

Lets look on the following example:

```
class_name  year student_id  grade   exam-id
---------   ---- ---------   -----   ------- 
A           2012  3         90      1
A           2012  4         80      1
A           2012  5         70      1
A           2013  3         90      1
A           2013  4         100     2
A           2013  5         70      1
A           2014  3         90      1
A           2014  4         100     2
A           2014  5         75      3
A           2015  3         85      4
A           2015  4         95      4
A           2015  5         80      4
A           2016  3         85      4
A           2016  4         90      5
A           2016  5         90      5
```

Above table displays a class named 'A' which has 3 students along with there grades in specific exam in each year. Each year there is a new exam, and if the student decides to take the exam, the table get filled with the new exam-id, else(i.e. the student didn't take the exam) the table get filled again with the old exam-id (and the old grade)

Now, I want to display in each year the number of students that actually took the exam.

So the result should look like:

```
class_name  year  num_of_students_took_the_exam
---------   ----  -----------------------------
A           2012   3
A           2013   1
A           2014   1
A           2015   3
A           2016   2
```

I know how to do it with select and group-by ,and the select and group-by the result. But it seems too complicated.

```
select class_name, year, count(year)
from
  (select 
     class_name, min(year) as year, student_id, grade, min(exam-id) 
   from 
     my_table
   Where 
     class_name = 'A'
   group by
     class_name, student_id, grade)
group by
  class_name, year
```

Is there any simple sql script that returns the same result?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you show your query for *with select and group-by ,and the select and group-by the result*. I doubt it can be simplified.

Comment: Please post your `too complicated query`?

Comment: On a sidenote: This is a strange table design. Consider changing it. One would rather expect a table of exams (A/1/2012, A/2/2013, ...) and a table of exams taken. As is, the table allows for student 1 to take A/1 in 2012 and student 2 to take it in 2013, which must not be allowed, however, according to your description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query can be simplified a bit, but you can't remove the nested aggregate:

```
select class_name, year, count(*)
from
  (select 
     class_name, min(year) as year, student_id, exam_id
   from 
     my_table
   Where 
     class_name = 'A'
   group by
     class_name, student_id, exam_id) -- don't group by grade, there might be two different exams with the same grade
group by
  class_name, year
```

Rewriting with LAG (or ROW_NUMBER) is probably not simpler/more efficient

Answer (score 0):

could you do...

```
select distinct class_name, year, count (distinct class_name+'-'+min(year)+'-'+student_id+'-'+exam_id) as cnt
from my_table
where class_name = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `row_number()` function with *grouping* by `class_name, year, student_id, exam_id` ( main logic depends on the grouping by `student_id`, `exam_id` ) as in the following :

```
  select class_name, year, 
         count(rn) as num_of_students_took_the_exam
    from
  (  
    select class_name, year,exam_id,student_id, 
           row_number() over (partition by student_id, exam_id order by year ) as rn
      from Exams 
     group by class_name, year, student_id, exam_id   
     order by class_name, year, student_id, exam_id
  )
  where rn = 1
  group by class_name, year;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb700/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a list of which exams appeared in which years.  In your case, you are using a sequential number.  If this is how your data is really structured, then you can do:

```
select year, count(*)
from example e
where year - exam_id = 2012
group by year;
```

In practice, such a query would not use magical math.  Instead, something like this:

```
select e.year, count(*)
from example e join
     exams ee
     on e.exam_id = ee.exam_id
where e.year = ee.year
group by e.year;
```